# MySQL - fulltext search - operators to search in a part of string

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a problem with fulltext search. In my column: `filter_name` I have a record which is: `kalah` and now I'm trying to get this record using fulltext search. Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`filter_name`, `filter_client_phone`) AGAINST (\'+'.trim($post.'*\' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

and the $post is: "al", so query finally looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`filter_name`, `filter_client_phone`) AGAINST (+al* IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but this query doesn't search my result which is: k**al**ah. When the $post is: "kal" - that's work fine.

How I have to change my sql query to search a words using substring which is a part of full-string in my database?

Thanks.

Comment: FULLTEXT typically ignores "words" of length less than three characters.  See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: @O.Jones when I change "al" to "ala", the problem is the same.

Comment: A fulltext search can only find words that *start* with your search input, not substrings inside a word. To find text in random positions inside your string, use (e.g.) `where filter_name like '%al%' or filter_client_phone like '%al%' `.